# Excel Online - few charts or group of charts to image to email body

Tags: excel, power-automate

Is it possible to paste multiple charts in an email body as one image from excel online?
I am currently using the .getchart.getimage function to paste an image into an email body using powerautomate and it works great. Unfortunately the problem arises when I want to copy and paste several charts in excel online as an image in email body.

Unfortunately, I can not find a solution for this.
Thank you in advance for your help :)

Problem is with size of charts when i have 4 images of chatrs in email body. In full size outlook window there is no problem like on picture below and email looks good:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mhofk.png

When i reduce email windows i got problem like in link below.
All images are smaller but without charts and email looks really poor. This email has over 1000 recipients and I can't send it that way.
Problem:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/0y8vw.png

Comment: Why is it a problem?  Can you add more information, screenshots, your script, etc.?

Comment: @Skin thank you for your answer. I added screenshots and what problem thoroughly i have.